# Can a stack be accessed like an array?

Tags: c++, stack, size

Currently in a program I am making I have to look at the top of a stack, and I was curious if I could do something along the lines of this?

```
int N, temp;
N = stack.size();

temp = stack[N];
```

Just a question, I'm not sure if a "pop" method would be the correct option in this situation.

Comment: Are you referring to a specific `stack` implementation (e.g. `std::stack<...>`, from the standard library), or stacks in general?

Comment: from the standard library, I'm just getting into stacks so I expect I may have not used the correct syntax

Comment: Now is a good time to get used to reading C++ library references like this one: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/ Accessing the `stack` through the `[]` operator is not listed as one of its abilities under "Member Function".

Comment: [**Or this one**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)